# Fallback if popper.js fails to load

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, cdn, fallback, popper.js

How do I test that popper.js has loaded so that I can fallback from a CDN to a local copy?

Popper is required by Bootstrap 4 and must be loaded first.  I would like to use the same bootstrap fallback technique I use below so that if the popper.js CDN fails, the browser falls back to loading popper.js from my server.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>if(typeof($.fn.modal) === 'undefined') {document.write('<script src="local/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>')}</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check the Popper variable.

If its type is "undefined" then it Popper has failed to load and you can fallback to a local copy:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script>if(typeof(Popper) === 'undefined') {document.write('<script src="static/lib/popper.min.js"><\/script>')}</script>
```

--

**February 2019 Update**

Since Chrome >55 now "intervenes" on some document.writes that include script tags (such as users on 2G mobile), but, if the document.write references the same domain or TLD+1 (ie, a script on static.mydomain.com referenced from a html file on www.mydomain.com), then Chrome won't intervene and stop the script download.  So for now the method above works fine.  I've also evolved the code a little:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.Popper || document.write('<script src="static/lib/popper.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

One other change to consider is to put the document.write here into a function and make an event call to your preferred analytics provider so that you can track when your site is falling back to a local copy of an external script, rather than it just silently doing so.